# Searchable dropdown in windows form?

Tags: c#, .net, forms

I have an application that's a front end to another server-side application. Users of the app can make a "rule" in the application and assign it a "justification." The problem is that there are around 4,000 justifications. Assigning a justification is a requirement. Currently I have it in a dropdown, but I have had many feature request for there to be a way to search this dropdown, or type something in to narrow the search field. Any suggestions on how I could achieve this? Never seen anything like it in a windows form. Closest thing I can think of is Google autocomplete.

Comment: Are there any categories to the justifications?  If there are you could have a series of drop downs where you narrow down more and more, each time filtering the next drop down based on previous choices.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [ComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.aspx), and set the property [AutoCompleteMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.autocompletemode.aspx) to AutoCompleteMode.Suggest or AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend

ComboBox is specifically made to be a drop-down with auto-complete/inline searching.

Comment: The trouble I've had with this is that the combobox suggestion only goes so far. After about 10-12 characters, it doesn't function correctly. For example, I searched for "Error: 'The syste" and it didn't match the appropriate justification, but suggested another one that started "Error: 'Unknown'". Strange.